# How to wait for button to appear in pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Hi I am using pywinauto to automate an installation script and I am done with almost all of the work but when my system has to wait for installation to complete there is graphical progress bar appearing and after finishing it there is a new finish button appearing but I am unable to click it . please help

```
app.top_window().Finish.Wait(120,3,"enabled visible ready").click()
```

I enter this command after pressing the last next button.

Comment: Please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html